# Is there a way to add errors from build step in TeamCity to the email notification?

Tags: email, powershell, teamcity

I have a Powershell build step, and I'd like to add some messages fromt the script to the resulting email that is sent to people on the notification list.  I see this happen for tests where the number of failures and the error is added to the email.  But, how can I add my custom messages from the PowerShell build step to the resulting email?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using service messages? 
See here:http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity

You could use

```
write-host "##teamcity[message text='Its broken again' errorDetails='Your exception message' status='FAILURE']"
```

Comment: Doesn't that only go into the logs?  I'm looking for something that goes into the email notification.  But perhaps this also goes into that.

Comment: well thats what i was thinking.

Comment: Its does if the message is in the format: Write-Host "##teamcity[buildStatus status='FAILURE' text='Its in a heap']"

Answer (score 0):

In order for the errors to be included in emails, I found I needed to add "compilationStarted" and "compilationFinished" tags, e.g:

##teamcity[compilationStarted compiler='Solution.sln']

##teamcity[message text='1>File.cpp(1): error C2065: "stackoverflow" : undeclared identifier' status='ERROR']

##teamcity[compilationFinished compiler='Solution.sln']

I use a Python script to parse the output from devenv, looking for specific strings to add as errors and warnings. The email adds these under a "compilation errors" section.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to pipe the output of an error that occurred in the Powershell script you are running then try piping the error object to a TeamCity service message after it has been caught

This is untested code but it might work for you:

```
trap [SystemException]
{
    write-host "##teamcity[message text='An error occurred' errorDetails='$_' status='ERROR']";exit 1
}
```

OR

```
try
{
    # Something...
}
catch
{
    write-host "##teamcity[message text='An error occurred' errorDetails='$_' status='ERROR']";exit 1
}
```